# how to find image files without extensions (on macos 10.8)

Tags: macos, grep

i have an app that has decided to die which had a library of images it stored on my hard drive in a series of guid-like folders. the files themselves have no file extensions, there must have been an internal database (unrecoverable/corrupt) that associated the file itself with its name/extension/mime. So to get my stuff back out I'd like to be able to search the disk to at least identify which of the files are images (jpeg and png files). I know that both jpeg and png have particular byte sequences in the first few bytes of the files. Is there a grep command that can match these known byte sequences in the first few bytes of each file in the massively nested file system structure that I have (e.g. folders 0 through f, each containing folders 0 through f, nested several levels deep, with files with uid filenames.

Comment: The command `file` will tell what you are after. But the `identify` command from ImageMagick has a better chance to detect more different image formats.

Answer (score 0):

Starting at the current directory `.`:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -J fname -0 -P 4 identify -ping fname 2>|/dev/null
```

This will print the files that ImageMagick can identify, which are mostly images, but there are also exceptions (like txt files). ImageMagick is not particularly fast for this task either, so depending on what you have available there might be faster alternatives. For instance, the `PIL` package for Python will make this faster simply because it supports a lesser amount of image formats, but which might be enough for your task.